# Fill with water and stones

Tags: ocean-simulation

I am trying to build a meadow scene (based on Andrew Price's tuts) and I want to fill the riverbed with sticks and stones and in the end with water.

Referrence> [image]

But I want to see through the water surface. So whats the best way to achieve that? With multiple particle systems or with a plane that I give a water effect? Any Thoughts?

Thnx

Comment: related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/28802/2d-flow-simulation-over-a-surface/28836#28836 just make the water transparent/translucent/reflective... maybe start with a glass shader...

Comment: related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7919/river-simulation-different-approaches-than-fluid-simulation and http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/32214/how-can-i-create-a-flowing-rippling-water-surface-effect-that-follows-the-curve

Answer (score 2):

My choice would be.

1. For the river, Mesh Plane with animated water material.
2. Particle system as a tool to randomly distribute the stones and branches.